# Are large temperature variation in a water heater normal?

Tags: water-heater, temperature, hot-water

I live in an apartment with a water tank and heater in the laundry room. About a month ago I had the heater replaced because it was leaking on my floor. Right after it was installed I noticed the water was nice and hot (dial read 120°F).

Recently I've noticed the water seems cooler and cooler to the point that today I turned the shower handle all the way and it felt luke-warm. The temperature reading was 75°. I decided to let the shower run a little and the temperature rose after about 5-10 minutes to 95°, which was certainly hotter, but still not the nice 120° that it was originally.

I checked the dial on my heater and it was set to "B" on the Low, A, B, C, Very Hot scale.

Is this normal for this much variation, or should I have someone come look at the heater (or maybe something I can tweak)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a variation is not normal unless you are using an abnormally high amount of water so that the water heater does not have enough time to recover.  Otherwise, since the heater worked properly when first installed, I would recommend calling the installer.

Comment: It may not be an "*abnormally high amount of water*", just an amount of water over what the heaters capacity is.  If a smaller tank was installed, it's likely that the hot water will not last as long. However, if you're not using water, you shouldn't see the temperature of the water in the tank drop too much.